# Git rerere file pattern?

Tags: git, git-rerere

Can git `rerere` be configured so it only remembers and applies merge resolutions on certain file patterns?  Ie: just on the pattern `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one, but I can think of a solution which involves invoking a script immediately after a merge operation (but before any manual resolving).

First off, the cache of conflict resolutions (`.git/rr-cache`) is **stored by blob hash rather than by file path**. There is nothing to indicate which file the resolutions actually came from, so I think hacking away at that directory would not be a viable solution.

[This quote](http://markmail.org/message/yh7tsa55vqeywz5w) from maintainer Junio Hamano also hits on the fact that rerere is per-merge and not per-file:

> There is no "I do not care if there are good resolutions remembered
>   that do not have anything to do with the current merge, just remove
>   all of them"---that is what "rm -fr .git/rr-cache" is for.

...which of course is not useful for you because selectively deleting files from `.git/rr-cache` is not well suited for automation in your use-case.

The feature to exploit may be the `forget` sub-command which takes a pathspec. The "forgetting" can only happen during the context of a merge however, which makes it fundamentally different than something like  `.gitignore` which you can apply statically.

**But, conceivably you could have a post-merge hook that invokes a script which**:

*Iterates over the conflicted files:*

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

*For every file that you want to "un-rerere", forget it:*

```
git rerere forget -- path/to/file
```

*...and restore the conflict:*

```
git checkout -m path/to/file
```

Then, continue on with the merge per-usual leaving the rerere resolutions for the files you want remembered intact.

The list of files to have "rerere remembered" could be checked into the repository (perhaps in a file called `.reremember`) and queried from the script.